# Please, help me understand tensor products

Tags: modules, representation-theory, tensor-products

I'm reading Webb's A Course in Finite Group Representation Theory, but I keep getting stuck on tensor products and keep rereading the definition, but I just don't really understand it.

$R$ is  ring and $H\leq G$ subgroup and $V$ an $RH$-module.

$$RH\otimes_{RH}V \cong V$$

So I think the first side of the isomorphism should have elements in the form of
$r_1h_1(r_2h_2\otimes v)=rh(1\otimes v)$ for some $r\in R, h\in H$ and $V$ has elements in the form of $rhv$.

So the map

$$rh(1\otimes v) \mapsto rhv $$

should be fine, right?

Thanks in advance!

PS.:Recommendations on books about tensor products (that even I would understand) preferably with exercises and solutions would be welcome!

Comment: If $A$ is any ring, and $M$ is any left $A$-module then $A\otimes_A M\cong M$. One way round is $\sum a_i\otimes m_i\mapsto\sum a_im_i$, the other way is $m\mapsto1\otimes m$.

Comment: I found Tensor Products difficult when I first encountered them because it turned out that (as with many good mathematical ideas) in familiar contexts they represented things which were so blindingly obvious they barely needed to be said, and I didn't have much intuition for the unfamiliar contexts. But again, as with all good mathematical ideas, they turn out to encapsulate something of the "blindingly obvious" which enables good mathematical generalisation to those unfamiliar contexts. For me they were a bridge to the unfamiliar, but I did have to work at them.

Comment: It may be old school, but Hungerford's treatment of tensor products in the GTM book is so bottom-up and pedantic that I couldn't help but understand it by reading along.

Comment: thank you for your answers! 
@Randall thank you especially for the recommendation, as I see it has some chapters that I might want to read through!